# How to rotate folium CustomIcon

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I have dataframe; it has name, latitudes, longitudes and heading.

Heading value will between 0 and 360. According to the angle we need to rotate.

I printed my dataframe items inside folium map in following way.

```
df_counters = pd.DataFrame({'Name': names,'latitude':latitudedes,'longitude':longitudes ,'heading':headings})
locations = df_counters[['latitude','longitude']]
locationlist = locations.values.tolist()
print(locationlist)

map = folium.Map(location=[1.3521,103.8198],zoom_start=11.5)

for point in range(0, len(locationlist)):
    pushpin = folium.features.CustomIcon('/ship_icon.png', icon_size=(15,15))
    folium.Marker(locationlist[point],icon=pushpin, popup=df_counters['Name'][point]).add_to(map)
map
```

How can I rotate this folim custom item according to the heading value?

Comment: You can use `DivIcon` and rotate icon HTML element with the CSS `rotate` property.

Comment: Check out this answer... example of the above comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75733004/12081954